# Stability of non-hyperbolic critical point in two dimensions, where the linearization has one zero egenvalue

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-theory

I am having a two dimensional autonomous system

$S' = 2S^3+2S^2+\frac{1}{2}SA-\frac{3}{2}S-\frac{3}{4}A$

$A' = 4AS^2+A^2+4AS$

which exhibits a critical point at the origin $(S,A)=(0,0)$, and others. The eigenvalues of the linearization of the system at the origin yields

an eigenvalue $\lambda_1 = -\frac{3}{2}$ corresponding to the eigenvector $v_1=\left[\begin{matrix}1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right]$,

and an eigenvalue $\lambda_2=0$ corresponding to the eigenvector $v_2=\left[\begin{matrix}-1/2 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right]$.

Hence there is a center manifold tangent to the second vector. I am new to center manifold theory, but found some theorems which look easy to apply for simple cases in two dimensions in the book of Perko – Differential Equations and Dynamical systems (3rd ED), section 2.11. The theorem however requires the system to first be put in a specific form. I quote from the book on p. 150:

> We first consider the case when the matrix $A$ [that is the
>   linearization matrix at the fixed point] has one zero eigenvalue, i.e.
>   when $\det A=0$, but $\mathrm{tr}\,A\neq0$. In this case, as in
>   Chapter 1 and as is shown in [A-I] on p. 338, the system (1) can be
>   put into the form
>
> $\dot x=p_2(x,y)$
>
> $\dot y=y+q_2(x,y)$
>
> where $p_2$ and $q_2$ are analytic in a neighborhood of the origin and
>   have expansions that begin with second-degree terms in $x$ and $y$.

So I am certainly looking at such a case with one zero eigenvalue. However I do not see, how to bring it into the required form, and I need it in this form to apply the theorem which follows in the book right after.

The source [A-I] he quotes is A. A. Andronov, E. A. Leontovich, I. I. Gordon and A. G. Maier, *Qualitative Theory of Second-Order Dynamical Systems*, John Wiley and Sons, New York 1973. My library doesn't have it, it seems out of print, and I also couldn't find it anywhere on the internet.

The reference to Chapter 1 in his own book didn't help me either so far, but I will check that in greater detail.

Does anyone here have an idea how to bring the system into the required form?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the eigenvalues and eigenvectors to diagonalise the system. So, you choose your coordinate axes along the eigenvectors, and write
$$
\begin{pmatrix} S \\ A \end{pmatrix} = y\,v_1 + x\,v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} y-\frac{1}{2}x \\ x \end{pmatrix},
$$
which gives you the linear coordinate transformation $x = A$, $y = S + \frac{1}{2} A$. Hence, you obtain the system
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= \text{second degree terms},\\ 
\dot{y} &= -\frac{3}{2} y + \text{second degree terms}.
\end{align}
Now, rescaling time by introducing $\tau = \lambda_1 t = -\frac{3}{2} t$, you transform the system into the required standard form.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was extremely helpful! Allow me two follow up questions: (1) Is it guaranteed, that the flow in a neighborhood of the critical point in the $xy-$system will be topologically equivalent to the flow in the neighborhood of the original system? Is this universal for all systems which differ by a linear transformation? (2) If I wanted to analyse a critical point which is not at the origin, could I just do the same thing, or would I have to define shifted variables first, for which the critical point would then be at the origin? Thanks again!

Comment: (1) Yes, by the definition of what it means to be topologically equivalent, as long as the linear transformation is invertible (that is, the associated matrix has nonvanishing determinant). (2) You'd have to define shifted variables first. Feel free to accept the answer, btw! Happy to help, I'm glad that my answer has been helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot once more! Answer is accepted! : )